# Version error: es53 expects 4949 but module is 4969

Tags: google-apps-script

is anyone experiencing a similar issue? My script wont simply load..

Comment: Are you using HtmlService? Please paste in the code from your script so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been identified and a fix will be made immediately.